# Table of contents use section header colors in Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word

I am working in Word 2010.

I have a large document for which I have created a table of contents.   In my document I have used styles etc.   After the document was completed there are some sections which I want to show with a different font color.   It cannot be done via style changes as not all of the same style have the different color. The color is used to indicated an importance for certain areas.

What I would like to do is when I update the TOC have the sections that are a different color of font come to the TOC with their respective color.

Is this possible and if so can anyone give me directions of how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Only direct font formatting of headers is reflected in the TOC. Just change font color of a header (but not in style) and when creating TOC do not use hyperlinks.

Result below:

[image]

Comment: thanks however I need the table of contents to be hyperlinked as the document is very long.

Comment: To clarify  I want the table of contents to show for instance some in black and some in red however when I click on either the black or red in the table of contents I need it to take you to the section.

Comment: I don't know how to keep font color and hyperlinks at the same time. Consider using highlight colors instead of font colors - hyperlinks do not affect them.

Comment: Direct font formatting in the source headings should preserve the hyperlinking. However, in web view, it will still show as a hyperlink. It will not show that way in print view or in the printed result; the red should still show and it should be an active hyperlink.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can create different styles for each different header color.

And apply them as they belong.

[image: heading sample]

Here we have "Heading 1" and "Heading 1 - Orange".

Then, when you create your Table of Contents, you insert a Custom Table of Contents:

[image: custom toc]

And when you click "Options..." you will have your different Heading styles in the level of the Table of Contents that they belong, being them on level 1, or some subtitles, etc.

[image: tocstyles]

When you click OK you will have your TOC complete, without format other than the one corresponding to it.

[image: tocfinal]

Comment: thanks for the help....I followed the instructions and the document body comes out right with the red colored font but when I go to the table of contents it still comes out with all lines written in black.     What I would like is for the ones that are red in the document to be red in the table of contents so that the people who it applies to can find it right away.    Am I missing a step?

Comment: @LookingforWordadvice Do you have several levels on your TOC or only main titles with different colors?

Comment: I have the first two levels which have sections with  different colors

Comment: I have 4 levels altogether with level 1 and 2 having both black and red in it

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this using guidance from https://wordribbon.tips.net/T007123_Creating_a_TOC_that_Includes_Specific_Styles.html

To implement (that is, turn color on or off for a particular TOC entry), the document owner has to switch paragraph types, e.g., from Header 4 to a user-created Header 4 RED.

Details here:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1n02iuNvAvGiMFsPiOIJDRuNevUNetkBuwn3oq2NJ69k/edit?usp=sharing